# This is regarding vector spaces and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

In each of the followings, assume that $V$ is a vector space. Prove or
disprove whether $S$ is a subspace of $V$.

---

$(1)$

$V = \mathcal C^0\left(\left[0,1\right],\Bbb R\right)$

$S= \left\{f \mid f \in V \land \left[\forall x \in \left[0,1\right], f(x)\ge 0\right]\right\}$

---

$(2)$

$V = \Bbb R_n\left[X\right]$

$S = \left\{f \mid f \in V \land \operatorname{deg}\left( f\right) = n \right\}$

Comment: ...please...? What have you done so far, where are you stuck...?

Comment: FAQ section, LaTeX to write mathematics properly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1)$

Suppose $S$ is a vector space

Let $\Bbb 1:\begin{array}{ll}\left[0,1\right]\to \Bbb R\\
x\mapsto 1\end{array}$

You have that $\Bbb 1 \in S$

But since $S$ is a vector space, you also have $-\Bbb 1\in S$

But $(-\Bbb 1)(0)=-(\Bbb 1(0))=-1$

So $-\Bbb 1\not\in S$

Absurd.

---

$(2)$

Suppose $S$ is a vector space

Let $f\in S$

You have that $-f\in S$

So $f+(-f)\in S$, that is $\Bbb 0 \in S$

But $\deg(\Bbb 0)= -\infty \not= n$

Absurd.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is simply verifying if the definiton of subspace of a given vector space applies to you case. So, ask yourself the following: if i take two elements in $S$ is their sum again an element of $S$? Use the definition of sum of functions, then check whether this sum matches the definiton of $S$ or not. Then do a similar check for scalar multiplication: take a function $f$ in $S$, multiply it by a scalar(i.e. a real number) and check if the new function you get is again an element of $S$. As an example, take $f$ in $S$ in case (1), multiply it by a negative real number $k$. Is $kf$ again in $S$?

As for (2), how do sum of polynomials and scalar multiplication of a polynomial by a constant affect the polynomial degree?

Comment: thank you so much for the help!!!